# What am I doing wrong in the canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to javascript so sorry if my mistake is obvious! I am trying to draw an ellipse using the canonical form equation.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
        </canvas>
        <script language="javaScript">
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

        var HEIGHT = ctx.height;
        var WIDTH = ctx.width;
        function transform(p){
            return [ WIDTH/2 + p[0], HEIGHT/2 - p[1]];
        } 

        var a = 70; //length parallel to x axis
        var b = 30; //length parallel to y axis
        var h = 150 - WIDTH/2; //when tranformed this gives the pixel 150
        var k = -HEIGHT/2 - 100; //when transformed this gives pixel 100

        function y(x){
            return b*Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow((x - h)/a, 2)) + k;
        }

        var dx = a/2/100 ; //each quadrant is broken into 100 segments
        var pOld = [h - a/2, k]; //starting point
        var pNew = [0,0];
        var x1 = 0;
        var x2 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;
        var y2 = 0;
        var temp = [0,0];

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){

            pNew[0] = pOld[0] + dx;
            pNew[1] = y(pNew[0]);

            temp = transform(pOld);
            x1 = temp[0]; y1 = temp[1];
            temp = transform(pNew);
            x2 = temp[0]; y2 = temp[1];

            ctx.moveTo(x1, y1); ctx.lineTo(x2, y2); //x1, y1 -> x2, y2
            ctx.moveTo(x1, -y1); ctx.lineTo(x2, -y2); //x1,-y1 -> x2,-y2
            ctx.moveTo(-x1, y1); ctx.lineTo(-x2, y2); //-x1,y1 -> -x2, y2
            ctx.moveTo(-x1, -y1); ctx.lineTo(-x2, -y2); //-x1,-y1 -> -x2,-y2

            pOld = pNew;
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#232323";
        ctx.stroke();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what happens when you run that code? My guess is you'll get an error because you try to access the canvas element before it is parsed. Try moving the script element the end of body (after the canvas). Also `[x1, y1] = transform(pOld);` destructuring assignment doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: did you check the console or try to debug? there should be some undefined variable errors. it should be `p[0]` not `p1[0]` in `transform`function

Comment: @nnnnnn and z33m: "new to javascript" probably means that Broseph is not aware of dev tools.  Broseph: There are debugging tools built into most browsers today which will help point out where your javascript errors occur.  Check out this introduction (its out of date, but still a good intro): http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/

Comment: I made changes after using the error console to find them, and i changed things based on your suggestions. Still not working! are x1,y1 and x2,y2 always the same?

Comment: Is the canonical equation important or are you just trying to achieve an ellipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You values are NaN (Not-a-Number). Change these lines:

```
var HEIGHT = ctx.height;
var WIDTH = ctx.width;
```

to

```
var HEIGHT = c.height;
var WIDTH = c.width;
```

and you get proper Numbers. However, your `y` value is outside the canvas area - you will see this if you console.log the values. There seem to be some issues with the math in general which I don't address here, but in relation to canvas you should be one step further.